# Avro Deserialization fails when reading data from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I have serialized avro data using the following serializer.

```
public class AvroSerializer<T extends GenericRecord> implements Serializer<T> {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AvroSerializer.class);

  @Override
  public void close() {
    // No-op
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // No-op
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
    try {
      byte[] result = null;

      if (data != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("data='{}'", data);


        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder binaryEncoder =
            EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(byteArrayOutputStream, null);

        DatumWriter<GenericRecord> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(data.getSchema());
        datumWriter.write(data, binaryEncoder);

        binaryEncoder.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();

        result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        LOGGER.debug("serialized data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));
      }
      return result;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new SerializationException(
          "Can't serialize data='" + data + "' for topic='" + topic + "'", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

To deserialize it I used the following deserializer.

```
package com.rms.rsc.kafkaavro.util;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AvroDeserializer<T extends GenericRecord> implements Deserializer<T> {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AvroDeserializer.class);

  protected final Class<T> targetType;

  public AvroDeserializer(Class<T> targetType) {
    this.targetType = targetType;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    // No-op
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // No-op
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
    try {
      T result = null;

      if (data != null) {
        LOGGER.debug("data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data));

        DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader =
                new SpecificDatumReader<>(targetType.newInstance().getSchema());
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(data, null);

        result = (T) datumReader.read(null, decoder);
        LOGGER.debug("deserialized data='{}'", result);
      }
      return result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new SerializationException(
          "Can't deserialize data '" + Arrays.toString(data) + "' from topic '" + topic + "'", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

But now when I try to deserialize the data it shows the following error.

```
2021-03-12 15:45:47.138 ERROR 19984 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.rms.rsc.kafkaavro.util.AvroDeserializer.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:351) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:384) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:406) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:713) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:646) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:626) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar:na]
```

The property configuration is shown below.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // normal consumer
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.put("auto.commit.enable", "false");
        properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        // avro part (deserializer)
        properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", AvroDeserializer.class.getName());


        KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

and the error is thrown in the following line.

```
        KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

I have converted my data as `GenericData` before sending to kafka topic.What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed because I tried using the GenericRecord class to produce the schema. I wasn't passing the schema I used initially to encode the data. After passing the schema I was able to retrieve the data.

```
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader =
                new SpecificDatumReader<>(targetType.newInstance().getSchema());
```

Here I was using a GenericRecord which had some other schema. Passing my own schema solved the problem.